# Issue in adding list of inputs in one transaction

Tags: kotlin, corda

I am trying to add the list of output in one transaction by using toTypedArray. in that list of output, each output has different signers and same contract. while am run the cordapp and hitting WS with some inputs, failed in contract verify and its throwing exception as List has more than one element.

```
val states:ArrayList<IOU>()
for(i in data.indices) {
    val state=IOU(data[i],initiator,acceptor)
    signers=state.participants.map{it.owingkey}
    txbuilder.addcommand(contract1,signers)
    states.add(state)
}

txbuilder.withitems(*states.map { 
    StateAndContract(it, Contract.ID) 
}).toTypedArray

txbuilder.verify(servicehub)

.
.
.
.
.
.

/*****Contract Code******////

out = tx.outputsOfType<IOU>().single()
"The sender and the recipient cannot be the same entity." using 
    (out.party1!= out.party2)
```

I have tried by removing `.single()` in contract. but I have no clue to proceed after that. After removing single, outputofTypes changed to list.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `single` throws an exception is there isn't exactly one item in the list. You need to loop through the states in `verify`, doing something like:

```
outputs = tx.outputsOfType<IOU>().single()
for (output in outputs) {
    "The sender and the recipient cannot be the same entity." using 
        (output.party1! = output.party2)
}
```

Comment: loop through the states in verify  in the sense?

Comment: Yes, inside verify.